# SQL database is not starting because primary keys

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL database won't initialize because all tables rely on primary keys/foreign keys that are in different tables. Is there a way to get this to compile  and not break?

Attached is code and ERD schema

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V2gZ.png)

```
CREATE TABLE boat 
(
    huID int NOT NULL,
    manufacturer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Model varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Year int NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
    color varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    condition varchar(20),
    CHECK (condition = 'New' OR condition = 'Used') ,

    CONSTRAINT boat_huID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (huID) REFERENCES Holding(huID),
    CONSTRAINT boat_Price_pk PRIMARY KEY (Price)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    customerID int,
    Name varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Customer_customerID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES invoice(customerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Holding
(
    huID int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT boat_huID_pk PRIMARY KEY (huID)
);

CREATE TABLE Salesperson 
(
    salespersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Customer_Name_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES Customer (Name) 
);

CREATE TABLE invoice 
(
    invoiceNumber int,
    customerID int NOT NULL,
    salespersonID int,
    Price int NOT NULL,
    huID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT boat_huID_fk REFERENCES Holding(huID),

    CONSTRAINT boat_Price_pk 
        FOREIGN KEY (Price) REFERENCES boat(Price),
    CONSTRAINT Salesperson_salespersonID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (salespersonID) REFERENCES Salesperson (salespersonID),
    CONSTRAINT Customer_customerID_pk PRIMARY KEY(customerID)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create tables *in order* so that tables - that reference other tables - aren't created *before* them.

In your case,

- reordering `CREATE TABLE` statements,
- removing foreign key constraint from `salesperson` (not entirely; create it with `alter table` at the end of the script) and
- renaming constraints in `salesperson` table (you named them in a *strange* manner, not uniquely)

does the job.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE holding (
  2      huid INT NOT NULL,
  3      CONSTRAINT boat_huid_pk PRIMARY KEY ( huid )
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE boat (
  2      huid         INT NOT NULL,
  3      manufacturer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  4      model        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  5      year         INT NOT NULL,
  6      price        DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL,
  7      color        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  8      condition    VARCHAR(20),
  9      CHECK ( condition = 'New'
 10              OR condition = 'Used' ),
 11      CONSTRAINT boat_huid_fk FOREIGN KEY ( huid )
 12          REFERENCES holding ( huid ),
 13      CONSTRAINT boat_price_pk PRIMARY KEY ( price )
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE salesperson (
  2      salespersonid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  3      name          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  4  --    CONSTRAINT Customer_Name_fk
  5  --        FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES Customer (Name)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE invoice (
  2      invoicenumber INT,
  3      customerid    INT NOT NULL,
  4      salespersonid INT,
  5      price         INT NOT NULL,
  6      huid          INT NOT NULL
  7          CONSTRAINT inv_huid_fk
  8              REFERENCES holding ( huid ),
  9      CONSTRAINT inv_price_pk FOREIGN KEY ( price )
 10          REFERENCES boat ( price ),
 11      CONSTRAINT salesperson_salespersonid_fk FOREIGN KEY ( salespersonid )
 12          REFERENCES salesperson ( salespersonid ),
 13      CONSTRAINT customer_customerid_pk PRIMARY KEY ( customerid )
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE customer (
  2      customerid INT,
  3      name       VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
  4      address    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  5      phone      INT NOT NULL,
  6      CONSTRAINT customer_customerid_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customerid )
  7          REFERENCES invoice ( customerid )
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE salesperson
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT customer_name_fk FOREIGN KEY ( name )
  3          REFERENCES customer ( name );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have circular foreign key constraints, define one constraint of the circle separately using an `ALTER`.

The pattern is:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ... -- other cols
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ..., -- other cols
  CONSTRAINT T1_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES T1(ID)
);
```

Create other tables with FKs to previously defined tables.

Then complete the circle with an FK from the first table to the last table via an `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD CONSTRAINT T2_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES T2(ID);
```

Alternatively, if it's too hard to keep track of what depends on what, you can just define *all* foreign keys using `ALTER`.

Comment: I would say a better way to resolve this circular dependency is to completely redesign the model. Because this same circular dependency will not allow to insert anything without `insert all` or deferred constraints or will not allow to delete rows. Strange references from `salesperson` to the (non-unique) `customer.name` and (very confusing) reference from `customer` to `invoice` are another issues, but they are out of scope of the technical problem of circular dependency

Comment: @astentx fair comment - the ERM seems convoluted. This answer only fixes the problem as stated. Inserting is no problem - just do inserts within a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to the above mentioned comments you may want to add in the cascade clause so if you delete a parent row all the related underlying rows will also be removed.  Below is a test case.Use with caution.

In addition, I also provided a query that you may want to use to tell you what is related. In my example, I hardcoded the table name ''PARENT" but you may want to use a bind variable. Good Luck.

```
create table parent (
  id NUMBER(10),
  value      varchar2(30),
constraint parent_pk primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint child_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT parent_child_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES parent(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE grandchild
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint grandchild_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT child_grandchild_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id,value)
REFERENCES child(id,value)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);


insert into parent values (1,'a');
insert into parent values (2,'b');
insert into parent values (3,'c');

insert into child  values (1,1);
insert into child  values (1,2);
insert into child  values (1,3);
insert into child  values (2,1);
insert into child  values (2,2);
insert into child  values (2,3);
insert into child  values (3,1);
insert into child  values (3,2);
insert into child  values (3,3);

insert into grandchild  values (1,1);
insert into grandchild  values (1,2);
insert into grandchild  values (1,3);
insert into grandchild  values (2,1);
insert into grandchild  values (2,2);
insert into grandchild  values (2,3);
insert into grandchild  values (3,1);
insert into grandchild  values (3,2);
insert into grandchild  values (3,3);

SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual

PARENT_CNT    CHILD_CNT    GRANDCHILD_CNT
3    9    9

DELETE from parent where value = 'a';


SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual

PARENT_CNT    CHILD_CNT    GRANDCHILD_CNT
2    6    6

Here is a query you can use to show the relationships

with f as (
        select constraint_name, table_name, r_constraint_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'R'
     ),
     p as (
        select constraint_name, table_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'P'
     ),
     j (child_table, f_key, parent_table, p_key) as (
        select f.table_name, f.constraint_name, p.table_name, f.r_constraint_name
        from   p join f on p.constraint_name = f.r_constraint_name
        union all
        select 'PARENT', (select constraint_name from p                                where table_name = 'PARENT'), null, null from dual
     )
select level as lvl, j.*
from j
start with parent_table is null
connect by nocycle parent_table = prior child_table
order by lvl, parent_table, child_table;

LVL    CHILD_TABLE    F_KEY    PARENT_TABLE    P_KEY
1    PARENT    PARENT_PK     -      - 
2    CHILD    PARENT_CHILD_FK    PARENT    PARENT_PK
3    GRANDCHILD    CHILD_GRANDCHILD_FK    CHILD    CHILD_PK
```

So now when we delete from parent Oracle will check if there are tables with FKs referencing parent and will find table child. Then it will check one-by-one if to be deleted table parent row has children in table child. If not it will delete that table parent row. If there are children if will check FK action and since that FK has ON DELETE CASCADE Oracle will try to delete that table child row. At that point it will (same as with table parent) check if there are tables with FKs referencing table child and will find table grandchild. Same way it will check one-by-one if to be deleted table child row has children in table grandchild. If not it will delete that table child row. If there are children if will check FK action and since that FK has ON DELETE CASCADE Oracle will try to delete that table grandchild row. Since table grandchild has no child tables Oracle will delete corresponding rows in tables grandchild, child and then parent.